# Python loop not working for JSON dictionary?

Tags: python, json, loops

I have a script in python to fetch data and put it in a dataframe from balance_sheet and Profit&loss reports through API get requests for multiple locations. The function is written in a way to throw out the location ID's that don't fetch any JSON data from API get requests.

The function and loop work for balance_sheet get requests but doesn't work for profit&loss get requests.

Problems:
1) Though the JSON data isn't available for a few locations it still appears in the final dataframe for P&L whereas the same locations are emitted out when the script is run for Balance_sheet.
2) the JSON data provides correct values when made a single request on one location for the P&L report but gives incorrect JSON data when requests happen in a loop for multiple franchisees.

Overall, the function and the loop works absolutely fine for balance_sheet API calls but isn't the same case for P&L API calls.

Below I'm attaching the whole script to extract json data from P&L api calls and pick only certain accounts values and put them in a dataframe. In the end, export the df to mysql db:

```
import requests
import json
#import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import time
#from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
#import json_normalize
access_token = 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX'
url = 'https://api.******.com/v1/setup'
url_company = "https://api.******.com/v1/Reporting/ProfitAndLoss?CompanyId=1068071&RelativeDateRange=LastMonth&DateFrequency=Monthly&UseAccountMapping=true&VerticalAnalysisType=None"
url_locations_trend = "https://api.******.com/v1/location/search?CompanyId=1068071"
url_locations_mu = "https://api.******.com/v1/location/search?CompanyId=2825826"
url_locations_3yrs = "https://api.******.com/v1/location/search?CompanyId=1328328"
time.sleep(0.5)
ult_result = requests.get(url_locations_trend,
      headers={
               'X-apiToken': '{}'.format(access_token)})


#decoded_result= result.read().decode("UTF-8")
json_data_trend = ult_result.text
dict_trend = json.loads(json_data_trend)

locations_trend = {}

#Name
locations_trend["Name"] = []
for i in dict_trend["Items"]:
    locations_trend["Name"].append(i["Name"])

#ID
locations_trend["ID"] = []
for i in dict_trend["Items"]:
    locations_trend["ID"].append(i["Id"])

#creates dataframe for locations under trend transformations
df_trend = pd.DataFrame(locations_trend)
time.sleep(0.5)
#making a call to get locations data for under 3 yrs
ul3_result = requests.get(url_locations_3yrs,
      headers={
               'X-apiToken': '{}'.format(access_token)})

#decoded_result= result.read().decode("UTF-8")
json_data_3yrs= ul3_result.text
dict_3yrs = json.loads(json_data_3yrs)

locations_3yrs = {}

#Name
locations_3yrs["Name"] = []
for i in dict_3yrs["Items"]:
    locations_3yrs["Name"].append(i["Name"])

#ID
locations_3yrs["ID"] = []
for i in dict_3yrs["Items"]:
    locations_3yrs["ID"].append(i["Id"])

#creates dataframe for locations under 3 yrs  
df_3yrs = pd.DataFrame(locations_3yrs)
time.sleep(0.5)
#making a call to get locations data for under 3 yrs
ulm_result = requests.get(url_locations_mu,
      headers={
               'X-apiToken': '{}'.format(access_token)})

#decoded_result= result.read().decode("UTF-8")
json_data_mu = ulm_result.text
dict_mu = json.loads(json_data_mu)

locations_mu = {}

#Name
locations_mu["Name"] = []
for i in dict_mu["Items"]:
    locations_mu["Name"].append(i["Name"])

#ID
locations_mu["ID"] = []
for i in dict_mu["Items"]:
    locations_mu["ID"].append(i["Id"])

#creates dataframe for locations under 3 yrs  
df_mu = pd.DataFrame(locations_mu)


locations_df = pd.concat([df_mu, df_3yrs, df_trend])

df_final2 = pd.DataFrame()
count = 0
for i in locations_df["ID"]:
    if count < 3:
        url_pl = "https://api.******.com/v1/Reporting/ProfitAndLoss?DateFrequency=monthly&UseAccountMapping=true&VerticalAnalysisType=None&IncludeComputedColumns=true&OrderBy=&RelativeDateRange=LastTwoCYTD&UseCustomDateRange=false&CompanyId=2825826&Locations" + i
    elif 2 < count < 12:
        url_pl = "https://api.******.com/v1/Reporting/ProfitAndLoss?DateFrequency=monthly&UseAccountMapping=true&VerticalAnalysisType=None&IncludeComputedColumns=true&OrderBy=&RelativeDateRange=LastTwoCYTD&UseCustomDateRange=false&CompanyId=1328328&Locations" + i
    else :
        url_pl = "https://api.******.com/v1/Reporting/ProfitAndLoss?DateFrequency=monthly&UseAccountMapping=true&VerticalAnalysisType=None&IncludeComputedColumns=true&OrderBy=&RelativeDateRange=LasttwoCYTD&UseCustomDateRange=false&CompanyId=1068071&Locations" + i

    result2 = requests.get(url_pl,
          headers={
                   'X-apiToken': '{}'.format(access_token)})
    #decoded_result= result.read().decode("UTF-8")
    location = i
    json_data2 = result2.text
    if(json_data2 != ""): 
        final2 = {}

        dict_pl = json.loads(json_data2)

        final2["Months"] = dict_pl["ReportModel"]["ColumnNames"]
        final2["Location"] = [location]*len(final2["Months"])
        set = {"40015 Granite Installations","40017 Cristallino Installations","40018 Trend Installations","40019 Mosaic Installations","40021 Plumbing Fixtures Installations",
               "40030 Cabinet Refacing Revenue","40035 Cabinet Accessories Revenue","40040 Bath Installations","40045 Backsplash Installations","40050 Trend Distributer",
               "40900 Other Revenue","40999 Sales Discounts and Allowances","40000 Installation Revenue - Other","Total Income","50025 COGS - Consumables","Total 50000 Cost of Goods Sold",
               "Total 51000 Direct Labor","53001 Advertising Fund","53002 Royalties to RSG","Total 53000 Other COGS","Total COGS","Gross Profit","Total 61000 Advertising",
               "Total 64000 Auto Expenses","Total 65000 Ops & Admin Payroll","Total 66000 Sales Commissions","Total 67000 Office Expenses and Other",
               "Total 68000 Professional Services","Total 69000 Travel Expense","Total 70000 Operating Expenses","Total 71000 Finance","Total 72000 Insurance Expense",
               "Total 73000 Occupancy","Total 74000 Utilities","Total Expense","Net Ordinary Income","Total Other Income","Total Other Expense","Net Income"}

        def search(dict2):
            if len(dict2["Children"]) == 0:
                return
            for i in dict2["Children"]:
                if(i["Name"] in set):
                    final2[i["Name"]] = []
                    for j in i["Values"]:
                        final2[i["Name"]].append(j["Value"])
                search(i)

            if (dict2["TotalRow"]["Values"][0]["RowName"]) in set:
                final2[dict2["TotalRow"]["Values"][0]["RowName"]] = []
                for j in dict2["TotalRow"]["Values"]:
                    final2[dict2["TotalRow"]["Values"][0]["RowName"]].append(j["Value"])
            return

        for total in dict_pl["ReportModel"]["TopMostRows"]:
            search(total)    

        df_final2 = pd.concat([df_final2,pd.DataFrame(final2)], sort = False)
        df_final2.drop(df_final2.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
    else: print(i)
    count = count + 1
    time.sleep(0.5)

#manipulation of the dataframe

df_final2['Months'] = pd.to_datetime(df_final2['Months'])
df_final2['Months'] = df_final2['Months'].dt.date
#import dateutil.parser
df_final2['Location'] = df_final2['Location'].astype(str).str.replace('/',' ')
df_final2 = df_final2.fillna(0)

df_final2.dtypes

#truncating table in MySQL db
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb

db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "****", "********", "source_db")

cursor= db.cursor()

cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE profit_loss")

db.close()

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('**********') #change to connect your mysql
#if you want to append the data to an existing table
df_final2.to_sql(name='profit_loss',con=engine,if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: "but doesn't work for profit&loss get requests." What does this mean? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, what is the output and what do you want it to be instead?

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] that reproduces the exact behavior you are asking about.

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to write functions in your code. They can help you organize code in a meaningful way that makes it easier to reason about what it is doing.

Comment: One final suggestion: read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I have a similar script used to extract data from balance_sheet API calls. when I run that script it throws out all location id's in the console(I'm using Spyder) that don't have JSON data as an output from the API calls made. So, when I run the above script(which is for P&L API calls) it doesn't do the same.